# VBA Issue when sending an array to a destination in a worksheet - Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a bit of code that sends the values of cells selected using refedit to an array (to be used at a later date) and then outputting them to a selected range. however I get an

> Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object defined error

when I set DEST = ….

Please see the code below. When I hover over `mydestination` I notice it is empty. However, I don't understand why. I am hoping someone on here can shed light on why it doesn't work and ways to rectify it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim addr As String, partderivrng, cell As Range, thisbook As String, NROWSPDIV
Dim NCOLSPDIV
Dim mydestination As Variant, DEST As Variant
Dim Dataarray As Variant
'   Set abook = ThisWorkbook.Name
If RefEdit1.Value = "" Then
    Partderiv.Hide
    ERR1.Show
Else
    addr = RefEdit1.Value
    Set partderivrng = Range(addr)
    Windows(ActiWorkBook.Text).Activate
    Dataarray = Array(Range(RefEdit1.Value).Value)
    NROWS = Range(RefEdit1.Value).Rows.Count
    NCOLS = Range(RefEdit1.Value).Columns.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Set mydestination = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
         "What is the first cell in the destination range for data?", Type:=8)
    Set DEST = Sheets("Data").Range(mydestination).Resize(NROWS + 1, NCOLS + 1) '<<< this is where error occurs when debugging. 
    DEST.Value = Dataarray

    Partderiv.Hide
End If

ModPARM.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Set DEST = mydestination.Resize(NROWS + 1, NCOLS + 1)
```

mydestination is already a range (type:=8)

or with the sheet:

```
Set DEST = Sheets("Data").Range(mydestination.Address).Resize(NROWS + 1, NCOLS + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this removes that error but another one exists which says - Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Thanks that gets rid of the errors. But now I find it doesn't actually do what it is suppose to. When debugging I notice that mydestination is empty regardless of the fact I specify the cell in the inputbox.

Comment: Strange, 'mydestination' should still contain a range after calling the input box